# Magento Cluster Installation: Install twice or install once and copy (rsync) files over?

Tags: magento, ssh, cluster-computing

When installing a Magento Cluster with Two Web Servers and One Database Server - Is the best to go through the Magento installation process on each server OR to install on one server and and use `rsync` to copy across all files.

And what is the way to deal with caching between both web servers?

Comment: Thanks for that. I do accept answers, just those that actually answer my questions directly and lead to a positive outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to create a file share on the DB server and then initiate multiple layers of caching with Varnish and run both Apache and Nginx.

Answer (score 1):

best way for you is to go to amazon and purchase a book called "Continuous Delivery: Reliable Software Releases through Build, Test, and Deployment Automation (Addison-Wesley Signature Series (Fowler))"

however i would suggest to build a deployment pipeline based on git and fabric that pushes your code to each host with a "push of the button" you can sync media and other shared resources with rsync